# Configure Celery Beat to attempt to reconnect to Rabbit if connection fais

Tags: python, celerybeat

If celerybeat loses its connection to RabbitMQ it doesn't appear to try to reconnect, it just sits their quietly not doing anything (this is almost certainly due to the way I have configured it).

Is there a way to configure celerybeat so it attempts to reconnect to RabbitMQ when a connection has been dropped?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?
Even I am looking for a way to do so. Even a glitch in connection to RabbitMQ server causes a complete outage, unless celerybeat is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion on this issue on their Github page suggests that using redis as broker can solve the reconnection problem.

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3409

Reconnection is certainly not supported with RabbitMQ, which is disappointing. But I am not sure if redis as broker supports retries.

In my use case, retries aren't used, so I am myself planning to switch my celery beat broker to redis.